# Quick way to expand $\cos^{-1}(\cos^2 x)$ up to $O(x^2)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

For a part of a question, I need to expand $\cos^{-1}(\cos^2 x)$ up to $O(x^2)$ about $x=0$. It took me quite a while to get an incorrect answer. What are some quick and efficient offline (i.e, no alpha) ways to get a good approximation?

EDIT: To elaborate a bit more, the first order term can be confidently stated to be $\sqrt{2}x$ as this expression is the length of a hypotenuse for a right spherical triangle, which must reduce to the flat triangle hypotenuse. No "reasoning" like this could work for second order term so I had to take the cumbersome way.

Comment: What method did you try? Find the first and second derivatives at $0$?

Comment: @Aryabhata   yes.

Comment: Well, $f(0)=0$ obviously, and $f'(0) = \pm \sqrt{2}$, sign depending on which direction you're coming from (you can prove this with chain rule and $\sin(x) = \sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}$). As the derivative isn't continuous, is this really analytic at $x=0$?

Comment: Oh, you want a second-order term? That's not what I thought you meant by $O(x^2)$.

Comment: @Qiaochu +1 anyway, as what you did for 1st order was faster than what I would have done progressing routinely

Comment: @kuch nahi: I got +1 and -1 in my answer. I post it just to give an information to "What are some quick and efficient offline (i.e, no alpha) ways to get a good approximation?". As I see it is like using or not a pocket calculator. It is not a replacement for theoretical analysis as the calculator does not replace the arithmetic capabilities one should develop. I deleted it. If you want some information my e-mail is acltavares@sapo.pt.

Comment: @Americo I will admit it was a rather hasty downvote, as I was not looking for computer algebra system solutions. I have no way to repeal it now, if you can restore your answer with a trivial edit I can undo my downvote, as it had its own worth of showing the utility of SWP. By the way, [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+arccos(cos^2+x)+about+x%3D0) does a neat job as well.

Comment: @kuch nahi: I undeleted my answer.

Comment: @Kuch nahi: ... and made a trivial edit.

Comment: Just to inform: I edited my answer to add "of the first expansion" to "Here is a 'print screen'" and give the reference $(\ast)$ to the second expansion. Then I got -1. I will keep it deleted.

Comment: @Americo Just to inform: I am not the downvoter. I did print out all the answers, though, so I do have a copy of your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have $\cos^2 x = \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(|x|^4) \right)^2 = 1 - x^2 + O(|x|^4)$. Since $\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(|x|^4)$, it follows that $\cos^{-1} \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} \right) = x + O(|x|^2)$, hence

$$\cos^{-1} \left( \cos^2 x \right) = \sqrt{2} x + O(|x|^2).$$

**Edit:** Jyrti seems to be right. Writing $\cos^{-1} \left( \cos^2 x \right) = \sqrt{2} (x + h)$, we get

$$\cos^2 x = 1 - x^2 + O(|x|^4) = 1 - (x + h)^2 + O(|x|^4)$$

so we can get $h = O(|x|^3)$. Just for fun, writing $h = ax^3 + O(|x|^4)$ we get

$$1 - x^2 + \frac{x^4}{3} + O(|x|^6) = 1 - x^2 - 2ax^4 + \frac{x^4}{6} + O(|x|^6)$$

hence $a = - \frac{1}{12}$ and

$$\cos^{-1} \left( \cos^2 x \right) = \sqrt{2} x - \sqrt{2} \frac{x^3}{12} + O(|x|^4).$$

---

Note that these power series computations are much faster than repeated computation of derivatives using the chain rule. The manipulations I'm doing make sense in the ring of formal power series modulo $x^4$ or $x^5$ or whatever precision I care about, and in that generality there's no need to think in terms of complicated sums of products of functions (which implicitly carry information about the derivatives to all orders, which is irrelevant).

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, but by "up to $O(x^2)$" I meant to include the second term as well, as I need some estimate of the correction. I have added a clarificatory edit to my question

Comment: I think that the error term is actually $O(|x|^3)$. If there were a term like $a_2x^2$, with $a_2\neq0$, then when you substitute that to the Maclaurin series of cosine you would get a cubic term.

Comment: Is there any name for this style of computations. It seems driven by intuition, but it would be good to know if presentation of such a method exists somewhere.

Comment: @kuch: I don't know if this kind of reasoning is written up somewhere; it's probably folklore. Basically I am just aggressively exploiting Taylor's theorem. This might be worth a blog post...

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan - how do you go from $\cos(x)=1-x^2/2+O(x^4)$ to $\cos^{-1}(1-x^2/2) = x + O(x^2)$?

Comment: @robinson: take the cosine of both sides.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan - sorry if I'm being thick. I see how to get from the second equation to the first by taking the cosine of both sides and using the Taylor expansion of cosine which translates the $O(x^2)$ into $O(x^4)$. But we need to do the reverse, to go from the first equation to the second, right?

Comment: @robinson: write $1 - \frac{x^2}{2} = \cos (x + h)$ where $h$ is much smaller than $x$. Then expanding the RHS gives $1 - \frac{(x+h)^2}{2} + O(|x|^4)$ or $1 - \frac{x^2 + 2xh + h^2}{2} + O(|x|^4)$. Comparing the asymptotics on both sides we see that $h = O(|x|^3)$ (the stronger statement that is shown later in the answer).

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan - Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Qiaochu's answer is a general way and that method ought to be in your bag of tools.

There are some 'gotchas' with this problem (especially if taking an exam) though, and you need to be careful...

Consider the function

$$g(x) = 

\begin{cases} 
\cos^{-1}(\cos^2 x) & x \ge 0 \\
-\cos^{-1}(\cos^2 x) & x \lt 0
\end{cases}
$$

This function has the derivative $\displaystyle g'(x) = \frac{2\cos x}{\sqrt{1 + \cos^2 x}} \forall x \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$

Notice that $g(x)$ is an odd function.

Hence the power series will only have terms of the form $\displaystyle x^{2n+1}$ and so

$$g(x) = \sqrt{2}x + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$

The same reasoning we cannot apply to $\cos^{-1}(\cos^2 x)$, which is an even function, as its derivative at $0$ does not exist.

So basically, your question is incomplete when you say about $x = 0$. Technically speaking, as asked, the derivative at $0$ does not exist and so the Taylor series does not exist either.

i.e: in the $(0,\epsilon)$ neighbourhood we have

$$\cos^{-1}(\cos^2 x) = \sqrt{2} x + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$

while in the $(-\epsilon, 0)$ neighbourhood we have

$$\cos^{-1}(\cos^2 x) = -\sqrt{2} x + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$

Comment: Made the function $g(x)$ in displaystyle mode.

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry, it is enough to consider the case $x \to 0^+$.
Here's a rigorous and not too complicated way to derive the asymptotic equality
$$
\arccos (\cos ^2 x) = \sqrt 2 x - \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{{12}}x^3  + O(x^5 )\;\; {\rm as} \; x \to 0^+.
$$
From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions),
$$
\arccos x = 2\arctan \frac{{\sqrt {1 - x^2 } }}{{1 + x}},\;\; - 1 < x \le 1.
$$
Hence
$$
\arccos (\cos ^2 x) = 2\arctan \frac{{\sqrt {1 - \cos ^4 x} }}{{1 + \cos ^2 x}} = 2\arctan \frac{{\sin x}}{{\sqrt {1 + \cos ^2 x} }} = 2\arctan \frac{{\sin x}}{{\sqrt {2 - \sin ^2 x} }}.
$$
Next, from
$$
\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2 - x} }} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }} + \frac{1}{{4\sqrt 2 }}x + O(x^2 )
$$
we get
$$
\frac{{\sin x}}{{\sqrt {2 - \sin ^2 x} }} = \bigg(\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }} + \frac{1}{{4\sqrt 2 }}\sin ^2 x + O(x^4 )\bigg)\sin x.
$$
Then, from
$$
\sin x = x - \frac{{x^3 }}{6} + O(x^5 )
$$
we get
$$
\frac{{\sin x}}{{\sqrt {2 - \sin ^2 x} }} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\bigg(x - \frac{{x^3 }}{6}\bigg) + \frac{1}{{4\sqrt 2 }}x^3  + O(x^5 ) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}x + \frac{1}{{12\sqrt 2 }}x^3  + O(x^5 ).
$$
Next, from 
$$
\arctan x = x - \frac{{x^3 }}{3} + O(x^5 )
$$
we get
$$
\arctan \frac{{\sin x}}{{\sqrt {2 - \sin ^2 x} }} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}x + \frac{1}{{12\sqrt 2 }}x^3  - \frac{1}{{3\sqrt 2 ^3 }}x^3  + O(x^5 ) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}x - \frac{1}{{12\sqrt 2 }}x^3  + O(x^5 ).
$$
Finally,
$$
\arccos (\cos ^2 x) = 2\arctan \frac{{\sin x}}{{\sqrt {2 - \sin ^2 x} }} = \sqrt 2 x - \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{{12}}x^3  + O(x^5 ).
$$

Comment: what is 'x downarrow $0$'?

Comment: I posted a new answer.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help. (This answer is completely different from the original one.)